# Regex matching (anything)(dash)(numbers) and then replace

Tags: php, regex

I need a little help on a regex pattern.

I have some strings ending with a dash and a number to the end to the string.

Example:

```
asddasasdasddasadsdsa-1
asdasdasdasd-11
asasdasdasdasd-234
```

I want to remove the (dash)(number to the end of string) so I need to match them and replace them with "".

I want to remove the LAST dash that is followed **by only numbers** to **the end of the string**.

Examples:

asdasd-1-1 must be asdasd-1   (**last** dash and number removed)

asdasd-1-1a must not change (there is no "(dash)(**numbers only** to the end of string)" so nothing changes)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using this regex inside of another programming language?

Comment: i need to preg_replace or ereg_replace or something like that in php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$str = preg_replace('/-\d+$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation.